# I2S audio weak linked callbacks broken in C++ after converting code to a class structure

Tags: c++, arduino-esp32

I have rewritten part of my C++ (Arduino/ESP32) code in classes to better organise it.
One issue I have is that with the ESP32-audioI2S library there are no callbacks anymore.

So before I would just have declared the audio object:

```
Audio audio;
```

And while playing files it would send callbacks to e.g. audio_info.

Now audio is in KAD_Audio::audio (not static so it is only loaded when audio is needed).
Since I use the class the callback to 'audio_info' is however not working anymore. I have them declared in the class:

```
  void audio_eof_stream(const char* info);
  void audio_eof_mp3(const char* info);
  void audio_info(const char* info);
```

and e.g.

```
void KAD_Audio::audio_info(const char* info) {

}
```

In the documentation of the library it says that "The events are weakly integrated by the compiler. This means they can, but do not have to be used." I expect this is a straight forward issue on how it is linked and how it is declared to the compiler picks the functions up, but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: `KAD_Audio` -- When, where and how is the instance of the class created?  -- *(not static so it is only loaded when audio is needed* -- Maybe the instance has to be alive (not have gone out-of-scope) during the lifetime of the application?

Comment: Why raw pointers rather than smart pointers?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I solved it by just moving the code outside the class, and that makes sense, even though I would like to have it inside for tidiness.